# Sending Multiple Sms through SMPP

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smpp

I will come straight on my question.

1. I am using Logica smpp and I want to send sms to multiple numbers. below code giving exception.

   ```
   public void submitMulti() {
   String serviceType = "";        
   byte replaceIfPresentFlag = 0;
   String scheduleDeliveryTime = null;
   String validityPeriod = null;
   byte esmClass = 0;
   //######################
   //byte protocolId = 0;
   //byte dataCoding = 0;
   byte protocolId = 0; //0x00; commented is for flash
   byte dataCoding = (byte) 0x08; //0x18
   byte smsClass = 0x00;
   //######################
   byte ton = 1;
   byte npi = 1;
   byte priorityFlag = 0;
   byte registeredDelivery = 0;   //TODO registered delivery
   byte smDefaultMsgId =  (byte) 12; //0;
   try {
       SubmitMultiSM request = new SubmitMultiSM();
       SubmitMultiSMResp response;

       // input values and set some :-)
       String sourceAddress = "123456789012";
       int numberOfDestination = 10;
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDestination; i++) {
           request.addDestAddress(new DestinationAddress(new Address(ton,npi,"923458503302")));
       }

       // set other values
       request.setServiceType(serviceType);
       request.setSourceAddr(sourceAddress);
       request.setReplaceIfPresentFlag(replaceIfPresentFlag);
       request.setShortMessage("Hy");
       request.setScheduleDeliveryTime(scheduleDeliveryTime);
       request.setValidityPeriod(validityPeriod);
       request.setEsmClass(esmClass);
       request.setProtocolId(protocolId);
       request.setPriorityFlag(priorityFlag);
       request.setRegisteredDelivery(registeredDelivery);
       request.setDataCoding(dataCoding);
       request.setSmDefaultMsgId(smDefaultMsgId);
       String ipAddress = Bundle.getInstance().getValue(Bundle.Application_Contants.IP_ADDRESS.toString());
       int port = Integer.valueOf(Bundle.getInstance().getValue(Bundle.Application_Contants.PORT.toString()));
       long receiveTimeOut = Long.valueOf(Bundle.getInstance().getValue(Bundle.Application_Contants.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT.toString()));

       TCPIPConnection connection = new TCPIPConnection(ipAddress,port);
       connection.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeOut);
       customSession = new Session(connection);


       // send the request
       System.out.println("Submit Multi request " + request.debugString());
       if (!asynchronous) {
           customSession.submitMulti(request);
       } else {
           response = customSession.submitMulti(request);
           System.out.println("Submit Multi response " + response.debugString());
           messageId = response.getMessageId();
       }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       log.error(e,e);
       System.out.println("Submit Multi operation failed. " + e.getMessage());
   } finally {
   }
   ```

   }

And the Exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.smpp.Session.send(Session.java:1100)
at org.smpp.Session.send(Session.java:1173)
at org.smpp.Session.submitMulti(Session.java:727)
at com.noetic.topUpBooster.smpp.JarConnection.submitMulti(JarConnection.java:413)
at com.noetic.sdp.alerts.JarCheck.run(JarCheck.java:34)
Submit Multi operation failed. null
```

does anyone have idea?

Comment: What will be the connection type? t or r or tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is acting as ESME, a bind request (via BindTransmitter or BindTransciever) must be sent before any SubmitSM, SubmitMultiSM or DataSM can be sent.

Comment: Now it's not showing any errors. but the message is not delivered to the specified destination(msisdn).

Comment: As for this secondary problem: (1) all of your destination numbers are same.  I would try testing with unique destinations. (2) A bind request must have a valid username/password combination. I would check the response object to see if the bind request was accepted.

Comment: Well Thanks its working now. as there was some issue with the operator, I tried other msisdn of another operator and it worked like a charm and there was no issue of using same msisdn.  Thanks once again.

Comment: There is also the issue that not all SMSCs support `submit_multi`.